# How to generate an animated gif within Codename One

Tags: gif, animated-gif, codenameone

I am wanting to generate an animated gif in Codename One.  I would like to combine a user supplied image with some text that will transition across the image in some way.  I assume I will need to create seperate images for the text and combine them with the user image.  Is this possible with Codename One and if so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Codename One supports adding an animated GIF using the add animation option in the images section in the designer.

However, it sounds like all you are looking to achieve is some text transitions. I suggest you look at `Container.replace()` and `animateLayout()`. You can see samples of using them both in the Kitchen Sink demo under effects and layouts.

Comment: Thank you Shai.  You are always so helpful.  To clarify I am wanting to actually create an animated gif and save the file so that the resulting image can be emailed or posted and maintain the animation.  I don't use the designer right now, so I am looking for methods to achieve this. I am already drawing the text on the image I just can't seem to find a way to combine them as an animated Gif.  Does Codename One have this methods currently or will I have to import another library?

Comment: You can create a timeline animation (which can be created via add animation from a GIF) using the designer and load the res file dynamically using Resources.open when you send it to someone.